# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search - Json

Tags: jquery, json, typeerror

I have a JSON print out as `[{"comments":"ashdhasasbsd"},{"comments":"sdds"}]`. However my script is giving me the following error. Any idea what is wrong ?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '74' in Connected to MySQL<br>[{"comments":"ashdhasasbsd"},{"comments":"sdds"}] -
```

**jquery-1.10.2.js:997**

```
<a onclick="showUser('.$row['ID'].')" >Show Comments</a>    
<script>
    function showUser(str) {
          if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
          } 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'viewCommentsJson.php',
dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: str
        },
        success: function (data) {


            var response = "";
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                response += value.comments + '<br />';
            });
            $('#txtHint').html(response);
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: pass the `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax and see

Comment: You have to parse the JSON first, however, it looks like the server response is `Connected to MySQL<br>[{"comments":"ashdhasasbsd"},{"comments":"sdds"}]`, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling are you saying that it is not valid because there is `Connected to MYSQL<br>` in the front ?

Comment: @Arun P Johny @FelixKling I have solved the problem. I have added the `datatype:json` as well as removing my echo statement for `connect to MYSQL.` Thanks for the help

Comment: Yep and great that you solved it :)

Answer (score -1):

On The viewCommentsJson.php page please return data in json format like:

```
echo json_encode($dat);
```